# Why is video currentTime and duration undefined accessing from JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm scratching here and I can't see the reason currentTime and duration from video html5 tag is undefined when I try call it from a simple alert, see fiddle below:

[am I missing something?](http://jsfiddle.net/cwdh6z08/)

```
<video autobuffer controls autoplay id="vd" height="170" width="170">
  <source id="mp4" src="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<br>
<br>

<span id="spDisplay">Some Info</span>
<br>
<br>
<a href="#" id="lkDo">Do Something</a>

$( "#lkDo" ).click(function() {
    alert($("#vd").currentTime);
    alert($("#vd").duration);
  //$("#spDisplay").html();
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work on the jquery object. Try:

```
alert($("#vd")[0].currentTime);
alert($("#vd")[0].duration);
```